Is there a way to access all parameters inside U3 gate in Qiskit Transpiled Quantum Circuit without looking every circuit one by one?
I built this Qiskit Circuit and I need help to access inside U3 gates parameters defined by Qiskit itself. Here's my code:
import qiskit
import numpy as np
import math
from scipy.linalg import expm as expMatrix # Added after a comment

N_features=2

N_QUBITS=math.ceil(np.log2(N_features)+1) #Circuit number of QuBits
QUBITS=[i for i in range(N_QUBITS)]

qc = QuantumCircuit(N_QUBITS)
qc.h(QUBITS)

tx = np.random.rand(N_features)
tw = np.random.rand(N_features)
sigmaE = np.diag(tx)*tw.T

matrix_pauli_x=np.array([[0,1],[1,0]]) # Pauli x
matrix_pauli_y=np.array([[0,-1j],[1j,0]]) # Pauli y
matrix_pauli_z=np.array([[1,0],[0,-1]]) # Pauli z
sigmaQ=matrix_pauli_x+matrix_pauli_y+matrix_pauli_z 
  
#Unitary Operator
U=np.matrix(expMatrix(1j*np.kron(sigmaQ,sigmaE)))
qc.unitary(U,QUBITS)
display(qc.draw("mpl"))

tqc=transpile(qc, optimization_level=3, basis_gates=["u3", "cx"], seed_transpiler=1)
display(tqc.draw("mpl"))

The outputs:


I need to access the complete range of the parameters inside the U3 gates after the transpilation without looking one by one. Is it possible?

It is unclear how you want to identify the location of each U3 gate, but assuming you have a plan for how to do that, here's a simple solution. I am using the QuantumVolume class in qiskit because I can't run your code since it is incomplete (expMatrix is not defined).
Here's the circuit I used:
from qiskit import transpile
from qiskit.circuit.library import QuantumVolume

qc = QuantumVolume(2)
tqc=transpile(qc, optimization_level=3, basis_gates=["u3", "cx"], seed_transpiler=1)
tqc.draw()


The code below iterates over the circuits, assigns a label to each u3 it encounters and creates a dictionary of dictionaries where the keys are the gate labels, and the values are dictionaries with the qubit and parameter information of each u3 gate:
gate_val = 0
u3_dir = {}
for i, instruction in enumerate(tqc.data):
    if instruction.operation.name == 'u3':
        u3_dir['u3_'+str(gate_val)] = {'qubit':instruction.qubits[0], 'params': instruction.operation.params}
        gate_val +=1

For the example above, it produces the following output
{'u3_0': {'qubit': Qubit(QuantumRegister(2, 'q'), 0), 'params': [1.0440841760486674, 2.6641100650410037, -2.0921842414289618]}, 
 'u3_1': {'qubit': Qubit(QuantumRegister(2, 'q'), 1), 'params': [0.4348770135181953, 2.948693964124362, 1.752376305917334]}, 
 'u3_2': {'qubit': Qubit(QuantumRegister(2, 'q'), 0), 'params': [0.7186015627120356, -1.5707963267948966, -1.5707963267948968]}, 
 'u3_3': {'qubit': Qubit(QuantumRegister(2, 'q'), 1), 'params': [1.5649885951362232, -3.040653328145914, 0.0572782716826703]}, 
 'u3_4': {'qubit': Qubit(QuantumRegister(2, 'q'), 0), 'params': [0.1311802714869456, 3.552713678800501e-15, -1.5707963267949]}, 
 'u3_5': {'qubit': Qubit(QuantumRegister(2, 'q'), 1), 'params': [1.6713839441184557, 0.01023951313391791, -1.4691752037207917]}, 
 'u3_6': {'qubit': Qubit(QuantumRegister(2, 'q'), 0), 'params': [2.1676530225927464, 3.029968355026753, -2.0109779032643655]}, 
 'u3_7': {'qubit': Qubit(QuantumRegister(2, 'q'), 1), 'params': [0.8900220554542061, 1.061441598269739, -2.690128433740786]}}


thanks for the tip. I added the missing function. I would really appreciate if you could help again :)

There’s really nothing to be changed. Just use the second block of code I provided. It should work for your circuit too
